# heroku doesn't let me create a file even temporarly

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, heroku, next.js, node.js-fs

i just discovered that Heroku uses an Ephemeral File System, so i opted to use AWS S3 to store images and upload them. the problem i encountered is creating the file to upload it.

my app is built with NextJS and my app is hosted on a basic dyno in Heroku. this app is an api with no front end code.

here is the code i use to create the file in my app using 'fs' library:

```
if (
          !fs.existsSync(
            path +
              new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0] +
              ".csv"
          )
        ) {
          fs.writeFileSync(
            path +
              new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0] +
              ".csv",
            await csv.toString(true)
          );
        } else {
          fs.appendFileSync(
            path +
              new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0] +
              ".csv",
            await csv.toString(false),
            "utf-8"
          );
        }
```

this code creates the file normally in my computer.

the 'path' variable is created using either :

```
let folder = await fs.promises.mkdir(path, {
        recursive:true,
        mode: '0o755'
       });
```

or i pass it to my request body.

i tried different paths like NextJS public folder and the "/tmp" folder, i also created folders manually in both paths but no result.

after a bit of research i found that you can create files it just gets erased when the dyno restarts and that usually happens every 24Hrs or so.

so my request is if you know how i can create a file even temporally just enough time to upload it to AWS S3? or a way to upload a file (png, csv) that is not created in the file system?

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't write a local file at all. There are libraries to abstract the remote filesystem. But this should work. What value does `path` have? Where are you trying to write to the local filesystem?

Comment: You can create a file temporarily, but you **must** use that file within the same Heroku HTTP request. Creating a file in one request and then doing a second HTTP request (like via AJAX) may fail, as that second request may hit an entirely different dyno that doesn't have the file on it.

Comment: @Chris i tried the nextjs public folder `/app/public` or the tmp folder with `/tmp/`.

Comment: @ceejayoz i will try to upload the code in the same request, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @OuchouAyoub Be aware you can allow users to *directly* upload to S3 without ever hitting Heroku. As a bonus, this tends to be much faster. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/

Comment: @OuchouAyoub, don't use absolute directories. Heroku can choose to put your app anywhere in the filesytem. Use a path inside your assigned directory. (But as I said before, and as ceejayoz has also said, you should avoid writing to the local filesystem if possible.)